# upload docker image to google cloud platform: https://grc.io/v2/: Service Unavailable

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-container-registry

I'am trying to upload a locally created docker image (graalvm, docker desktop on Mac) to gcp (with a real project id).

I see the following error:

```
% docker push grc.io/<project>/facility
The push refers to repository [grc.io/<project>/facility]

Get https://grc.io/v2/: Service Unavailable
```

I set up gcloud auth:

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

and my `.docker/config.json` looks like this

```
{
  "experimental" : "disabled",
  "credHelpers" : {
    "gcr.io" : "gcloud",
    "us.gcr.io" : "gcloud",
    "eu.gcr.io" : "gcloud"
  },
  "auths" : {

  },
  "stackOrchestrator" : "swarm"
}
```

Running

```
echo "https://gcr.io" | docker-credential-gcloud get
```

provides a token.

What is the problem?

-- Update --

When I run this (works)

```
gcloud container images list --repository=gcr.io/<project-id> --log-http
```

it is talking to https://gcr.io/v2/token?... and the docker-credential-gcloud above is talking to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token.

Comment: add https to your push command?

Comment: the error message says https://.... Adding https gives another error `invalid reference format`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have a typo. It should be gcr.io not grc.io

Comment: oh my ;-)  Running the push with `gcr.io` does now complain that the project was deleted (which is correct). But it doesn't complain Service unavailable anymore so I guess that was the problem. Good catch :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/<project-name>/<app-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to replace the `<project>` in

```
docker push grc.io/<project>/facility
```

with your project id.

If you are not sure how to get the project id, you can get list of all the projects with their IDs via cli.

```
gcloud projects list
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending more time on this I found out that gcp has **container** registries and **artifact** registries (beta).

Since I don't get it running with the container registry I created a new test project and an **artifact** registry.

Setup is the same apart from the registry address.

After locally running

```
gcloud auth application-default login
gcloud beta auth configure-docker us-east1-docker.pkg.dev
```

my ~/.docker/config.json has the following `credHelper` entry

```
  "credHelpers": {
    "us-east1-docker.pkg.dev": "gcloud"
  },
```

Now I can tag & push

```
docker tag a01478beacf9 us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/test-2/facility/name
docker push us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/test-2/facility/name
```

The tag has 4 parts:

```
HOST-NAME              /PROJECT-ID/REPOSITORY/IMAGE
us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/test-2    /facility  /name
```

and it just works. :)